# How to set up my personal keyboard as standard input in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I created a small keyboard to replace the standard Android keyboard. What should I do to set my keyboard as standard input in my app?
Thanks

Comment: Don't. Use the system's default keyboard. Some people have physical keyboards you know! You can release your keyboard as a stand alone app people can use to replace default keyboard if you like. But different keyboards on an app by app basis is a usability nightmare.

Comment: I explain in detail my problem. Basically using my keyboard, the sizes of EditText does not match the text that I add. why?

Answer (score 0):

I think may be this help you. You can hide system keyoboard used class InputMethodManager. And after this make onFocusListener on your EditText and if you has focus call class yourself keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

for that first you need to create a keyboard layout... u have to customize that.. then include that keypad with your layout, where you need to display ur personal keyboard.. like this

`<include
        android:id="@+id/Kinclude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/keypad"
        android:visibility="invisible" />`

and write a click event for your edittext and display this keypad when you click edittext....

Thank you...